Не приходят телеграм апдейты
написал бота на вебхуках все работает, но в течение некоторого времени перестают приходить апдейты с групп. Хотя если добавить в новую будет все работать и через время перестанет. Версия aiogram 2.25.1.
Вот код запуска бота:
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware
from aiogram.utils.executor import start_webhook
import logging
from data.config import TOKEN
from main import bot, dp
from handlers import messages, admin_messages, callbacks

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
API_TOKEN = TOKEN
WEBHOOK_HOST = 'https://thegrin.ru'
WEBHOOK_PATH = '/webhook'
WEBHOOK_URL = f"{WEBHOOK_HOST}{WEBHOOK_PATH}"

WEBAPP_HOST = 'localhost'
WEBAPP_PORT = 3000

dp.middleware.setup(LoggingMiddleware())


async def on_startup(dp):
    await bot.set_webhook(WEBHOOK_URL)

async def on_shutdown(dp):
    await bot.delete_webhook()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_webhook(
        dispatcher=dp,
        webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH,
        on_startup=on_startup,
        on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
        skip_updates=True,
        host=WEBAPP_HOST,
        port=WEBAPP_PORT,
    )


